# How to handle the number of threads in a client-server java app?

Tags: java, multithreading

As the title suggests, I'm implementing a small project which allows clients to connect to server using multi-Threading to manage the connections. I would like to limit the connections and when the Server is full of requests, the other clients should be put in a queue, ex: the server only allows 2 clients to connect the server at the same time, the other clients until their turn.

This is my Server class

```
public class Server {

    static BufferedReader userInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    //Declare an instance of CommandParameter class

    static CommandParameter par;
    //Initialize a BufferedReader and BufferedWriter
    static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    static BufferedWriter bufferWriter;
    //
    static int port;
    static String serverData;
    static int proc_count;
    private static String command;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        command = userInput.readLine();
        System.out.println("Server is available");
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        processCommand(command);
        startServer(port);

    }

    public static void startServer(int port) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            //create a port for server in order to listen incoming connections
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            //allow client connect to server

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                new ThreadSocket(serverSocket.accept(),serverData).start();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Server starts fail");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void processCommand(String input) {
        //assign the user input to an String array
        String inputLine = input;
        int commandCount = checkCommand(inputLine);
        if(commandCount>3 || commandCount ==-1){
            System.out.println("Invalid command");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        //assign the user input to an String array
        String[] command = inputLine.split(" ");
        par = new CommandParameter();

        //JCommander parses the command to get the pairs parameter name and value
        JCommander jc = new JCommander(par, command);
        port = par.getPort();
        serverData = par.getServerdata();
        proc_count = par.getProc_count();
    }
    public static int checkCommand(String inputLine) {
        int count = 0;
        if (inputLine.contains("-port")) {
            count++;
        }else if (inputLine.contains("-data")) {
            count++;
        } else if (inputLine.contains("-proc_count")) {
            count++;
        } else{
            return -1;
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: you could use some kind of Semaphore?

Comment: Use either a thread pooling, so you have 2 "workers", any new request will either be scheduled or cancelled. Or you use an internal counter which increases when a user connects and decreases when a user disconnects. In that case you will need to implement a "failsafe" if the user disconnects but the command never exits; some kind of timeout.

Comment: Why not have a poke around an open source java webserver, like Tomcat, that already does this. See if that gives you any ideas...

Comment: @DaDaDom Yes, As you said, the client should be put in a queue when Server has fulled of requests. Do you have any example about thread pooling?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly where asynchronous IO becomes most useful. [large number of IO requests need to be handled by limited number of worker threads]. There are system calls in most of the modern operating systems allowing asynchronous IO operations. example, epoll in linux, IOCP in Windows, AIX and Solaris, KQueue in BSD flavors and Mac OS. In java, native non blocking calls are abstracted behind different SPIs - examples  - sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl, sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl , sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl etc.

What I recommend you to use is [Netty](http://netty.io/).

An example of servicing a large number of HTTP requests with using a smaller fixed number of threads is a simple task using netty API.

Sample bootstrap code with one listener thread and two workers will look like

```
public static void setupHTTPListeners()
{
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),
    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2)));
    -----
    -----
}
```

On the same context, one of the most popular read is here - [The C10k problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ServerSocket(int port, int backlog);` the backlog parameter is the maximum number of connections allowed.

Comment: I edited my question, the server only allows 2 client access the server and the others should wait until their turn

Comment: Then I can only recommend you to use an existing project (maybe Jetty, or Tomcat, are very lightweight).